# Making Buttons that Locate Themselves in a List

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create buttons that delete themselves. In the code below, I create some amount of buttons in a for loop, append them to a list, and grid them. I am able to delete and remove any button in a certain index position of the buttons list, but need to figure out how to make each button locate itself in the buttons list.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.totalButtons = random.randint(5, 25)

        # The buttons will be stored in a list
        self.buttons = []
        self.labels = []

        self.createButtons()

    def createButtons(self):
        for i in range(0, self.totalButtons):
            # Here I create a button and append it to the buttons list
            self.buttons.append(Button(self, text = i, command = self.removeButton))

            # Now I grid the last object created (the one we just created)
            self.buttons[-1].grid(row = i + 1, column = 1)

            # Same thing for the label
            self.labels.append(Label(self, text = i))
            self.labels[-1].grid(row = i + 1, column = 0)

    def removeButton(self):
        # When a button is clicked, buttonIndex should be able to find the index position of that button in self.buttons
        # For now I set it to 0, which will always remove the first (top) button
        indexPosition = 0

        # Takes the button (in this case, the first one) off the grid
        self.buttons[indexPosition].grid_forget()

        # Removes that button from self.buttons
        del self.buttons[indexPosition]

        # Same for the label
        self.labels[indexPosition].grid_forget()
        del self.labels[indexPosition]


def main():
    a = App()
    a.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to store them in a list?

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem the other day trying to find the index of a button in an list once it is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command = lambda idx=i: self.removeButton(idx)
```

lambda here is taking the value `i` from your range and assigning it to `idx` and passing into the function. This function call is now unique to each button and so they have a value corresponding to their index.

```
for i, btn in enumerate(self.buttons):
    btn['command'] = lambda idx=i: self.removeButton(idx)
```

Because you are deleting each button from the list you need to assign a new value to the command parameter to properly reflect where the new position of the existing buttons in the list are.

```
    def createButtons(self):
        for i in range(0, self.totalButtons):
            # Here I create a button and append it to the buttons list
            self.buttons.append(Button(self, text = i, command = lambda idx=i: self.removeButton(idx)))

            # Now I grid the last object created (the one we just created)
            self.buttons[-1].grid(row = i + 1, column = 1)

            # Same thing for the label
            self.labels.append(Label(self, text = i))
            self.labels[-1].grid(row = i + 1, column = 0)

    def removeButton(self, i):
        # Takes the button at index i off the grid
        self.buttons[i].grid_forget()

        # Removes that button from self.buttons
        del self.buttons[i]

        # Same for the label
        self.labels[i].grid_forget()
        del self.labels[i]

        # Assign new values for index position
        for new_i, btn in enumerate(self.buttons):
            btn['command'] = lambda idx=new_i: self.removeButton(idx)
```

Comment: What is idx? Could I set idx to any variable?

Comment: It's just a variable name I used to represent the index. You can call it what ever you want, even `i`. I just used a different name to avoid confusion